# Error: Unexpected , after substr function in R

Tags: r, date, substr

```
(
(substr(a$JOIN_DATE,6,7)) %in% 
                                (
                                  '(substr(as.Date(Sys.Date()-months(1)),6,7))',
                                  '(substr(as.Date(Sys.Date()-months(2)),6,7))',
                                  '(substr(as.Date(Sys.Date()-months(3)),6,7))'
                                )
 )
```

When I execute this code it gives me the following error:

Error: unexpected ',' in:
"                                (
                                  '(substr(as.Date(Sys.Date()-months(1)),6,7))',"

> ```
>                               '(substr(as.Date(Sys.Date()-months(2)),6,7))',
> ```
>
> Error: unexpected ',' in "                                  '(substr(as.Date(Sys.Date()-months(2)),6,7))',"
>                                     '(substr(as.Date(Sys.Date()-months(3)),6,7))'
>   [1] "(substr(as.Date(Sys.Date()-months(3)),6,7))"
>                                   )
>   Error: unexpected ')' in "                                )"
>                           )
>   Error: unexpected ')' in "                        )"

Comment: are you a lisper? try adding a `c` after `%in%` as in `%in% c(stuff)` since now you have `%in% (stuff)`

Comment: Yup.. got it. Thank you.